# Where can I send a post request (any service) to get reply from it and test if my API works?

Tags: post, web, get

Is there any service like Google search, but which uses post requests? So I could send one and get a reply?

Comment: A quick google search gave me https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: hurl.it for sending requests to your apu, and i need to send a request FROM my api  to somewhere and get any reply.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and I am very satisfied have a look